# Polymorphism in PHP: Virtual function overrides parent function but parent function still gets called

Tags: php

I have been programming in C++ but have moved to PHP for a while it seems like polymorphism is different in PHP.  I know that in PHP, all functions that are not private (i.e. public/protected) are in fact also virtual.  Here is my child class definition

```
class Child extends Parent {
   public function foo() {

   }
}
```

then my Parent looks like

```
class Parent {
    public function foo() {

    }
}
```

I want my child class to use all of the parent's code apart from the `foo()` function - I want the child to use its own `foo()` function.

The issue is that the parent's `foo()` is still called.  Interestingly, my IDE (NetBeans) says that it is getting overridden correctly.

I am using `$this->foo()` in the parent and child.. this should be ok yes?  It just says 'execute the function foo for the current object'.. maybe I'm going wrong here?

Comment: `Parent::foo` should not be called when doing `$child->foo()`. There's probably something wrong with your code. Can you post an example that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the help.  Turns out I was being silly.. I was submitting a page and on the page that the submit goes to, it created an object of the class that was defined on the submit pagee and I was including the file!!  Sorry :-S.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you call `parent::foo()`, the parent's `foo()` will not be called.

Answer (score 2):

just tried:

```
class Child1 extends Parent1 {

    public function foo() {
        echo 'c';
    }

}

class Parent1 {

    public function foo() {
        echo 'p';
    }

}



$class = new Child1;

$class->foo();
```

prints "c"

You doing everithing right.